# Using Prometheus PushGateway with OpenCensus Java Client

Tags: prometheus, opencensus, prometheus-java

I've got a CronJob running that I'd like to integrate OpenCensus into to export to Prometheus. However I currently have to add a 1 minute sleep after my job finishes to make sure that Prometheus has scraped my metrics.

I'd like to use the Prometheus PushGateway to avoid the extra sleep if possible, but I can't figure out how to hook it up to OpenCensus.

Here's the documentation for it that mentions it: https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-java/tree/master/exporters/stats/prometheus - it says the following:

```java
public class MyMainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Creates a PrometheusStatsCollector and registers it to the default Prometheus registry.
    PrometheusStatsCollector.createAndRegister();

    // Uses a simple Prometheus HTTPServer to export metrics. 
    // You can use a Prometheus PushGateway instead, though that's discouraged by Prometheus:
    // https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/#should-i-be-using-the-pushgateway.
    io.prometheus.client.exporter.HTTPServer server = 
      new HTTPServer(/*host*/ "localhost", /*port*/  9091, /*daemon*/ true);

    // Your code here.
    // ...
  }
}
```

However there's no examples of how I actually would use it with OpenCensus. Has anyone done it before, and how?

Answer (score 0):

I think you likely [don't want to|can't] use OpenCensus for what you want to do.

#### What OpenCensus does

OpenCensus pushes metrics to e.g. Stackdriver, Datadog etc. but, for Prometheus -- the request-response flow is inverted and metrics are generally pulled from an endpoint that renders metrics in Prometheus' exposition format.

OpenCensus's Prometheus exporter(s) -- and, for Java, the example you reference -- creates an HTTP server into which you'd pour your metrics (see [this](https://opencensus.io/exporters/supported-exporters/java/stackdriver-stats/) example as the principle is the same).

Prometheus -- or some other service that understands Prometheus' metric format -- would then periodically scrape this endpoint and ingest the metrics.

#### What Prometheus Pushgateway does

Your cron job will emit metrics that must be pushed into e.g. Prometheus Pushgateway. In this architecture, the Pushgateway *replaces* the OpenCensus Prometheus Exporter endpoint.

All you need -- possibly nothing more than curl statements added to your cron jobs -- is something that will generate HTTP requests and ship these to a Pushgateway. See:

https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway#command-line
https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway#api

Then you'd configure a Prometheus server to scrape the Pushgateway endpoint to ingest your cron job metrics.

HTH!